# cannot get back the date selected from DatePicker

Tags: android

I am trying to get back the date selected in the DatePicker which is shown in a dialog. I mean I have a ActionBarSherlock with a menu which when pressed opens a dialog which has a datepicker and a EditItem.Now when I select a date and the amount I want to get those parameters.but I get error.Can somebody please help me. I have copied my code below

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Add Detail").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_compose).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);

    Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.canelButton);
    final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);

    Button OKButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.OKbutton);

    OKButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("---------------",datePicker.getDayOfMonth()+" ");
        }
    });

    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: which error u are getting? plz also add log with question to get more help from us

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.hai.chequedate.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:44)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use `dialog` instance of Dialog if `DatePicker` Widget is placed in `custom`  layout. try it as:

`final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)dialogfi.ndViewById(R.id.datePicker1);`

Answer (score 0):

Its not a big task.. You can do it of your own.. I am providing you the link of the Android Developers.. Hope this helps [Link 1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)